# Is there a way to determine the differentiability class of the solutions of a PDE?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, nonlinear-system

For a project, I am obtaining the numerical solutions to the following (Cahn-Morral) equations for $y = (y_1, y_2)$:

$$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial t}=\Delta\left[f_i(y)-\alpha\Delta(2y_i+y_j)\right]; \qquad i\ne j $$

where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator, $\alpha$ is some positive constant (of the order unity) and the $f_i$s are functions of the $y$s.In my particular case I have

$$f_i=\frac{3}{10}\ln[y_i/(1-y_1-y_2)]-(2y_i+y_j)$$

where again $i\ne j$. This particular expression for the $f_i$s is obtained from Thermodynamic considerations (they are the partial derivatives of the bulk free energy density for a ternary regular mixture, where $y_3$ was substituted by $1-y_1-y_2$).

My question is if there is any way to know if the solutions are going to be of a differentiability class higher than $C^4$ (which I already know they have to be because the equation is fourth order). I am solving these over a square domain with periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: How do you know a "solution" is $C^4$, especially if you find them only numerically?

Comment: I am solving it via Fourier methods, so the Fourier series of the solution converges to a $C^4$ function as the mesh size tends to zero. If it didn't then the numerical implementation wouldn't be convergent, but the method is both stable and consistent so it has to be convergent as well. Additionally I have seen the actual results and taken up to their fourth derivative and they appear continuous, at least for my current mesh.